# print NSImage from cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, image, printing, nsimage, nsprintoperation

I'd like to print a NSImage but haven't managed to succeed yet.
I'd like the image via a standard print panel from my cocoa application.
Could anybody help me please?
Your help would be really appreciated!

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

See Printing [Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Printing.html). In particular, look at [Using a Print Panel](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/Tasks/UsingPrintPanel.html).